# Convert dates to pd.to_datetime where month could be either a number or month name

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a datatime data, their format is like `29062017` and `01AUG2017`. 
As you can see, the month is in the middle of data.

I want to convert this data to datetime, when I use `pd.to_datetime`, but it doesn't work.

Do you know a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does your column have mixed formats? Tif not, the first format is simple - `'%d%m%Y'` and the second is `'%d%b%Y'`. If yes, you'll need to do a little preprocessing before conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alternative would be to use a mapper and `replace` to substitute month codes with their numerical equivalent:

```
s = pd.Series(["29062017", "01AUG2017"]); s

0     29062017
1    01AUG2017
dtype: object

m = {'JAN' : '01', ..., 'AUG' : '08', ...}  # you fill in the rest

s = s.replace(m, regex=True); s

0    29062017
1    01082017
dtype: object
```

Now all you need is a single `pd.to_datetime` call:

```
pd.to_datetime(s, format="%d%m%Y", errors="coerce")

0   2017-06-29
1   2017-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: added some options you might find interesting

Answer (score 26):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)'s format arg:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(["29062017", "01AUG2017"])

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(s, format="%d%m%Y", errors="coerce")
Out[12]:
0   2017-06-29
1          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [13]: pd.to_datetime(s, format="%d%b%Y", errors="coerce")
Out[13]:
0          NaT
1   2017-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

*Note: the `coerce` argument means that failures will be `NaT`.*

and fill in the `NaN`s from one into the other e.g. using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [14]: pd.to_datetime(s, format="%d%m%Y", errors="coerce").fillna(
    ...:     pd.to_datetime(s, format="%d%b%Y", errors="coerce"))
Out[14]:
0   2017-06-29
1   2017-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Any strings that don't match either format will remain NaT.

Comment: This would've been one option. I was actually thinking of substitution followed by the conversion (as in my answer).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ my bet is this'll be faster, but I think both are good.

Comment: I thought so too, because regex based substitution is pretty slow in general. I did a benchmark on `s = pd.concat([s] * 100000)` and... interestingly... yours is `1.01s`, mine is `1s`. Neck and neck! Let me know if you see any different results.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ in my testing these seemed to be much of a muchness. I am a little disappointed at the speed of to_datetime, I had imagined it was cythonized but perhaps not?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ having - long ago - poked around in the python datetime library which pandas was using (perhaps it's something better/different now)... I won't be doing again in a hurry - datetime handling is a world of pain.

Comment: This is a neat solution (+1)! But it obviously works only with two different formats, but not with more. Does anybody have an idea of how to solve it? I thought errors = 'ignore' might do the job, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have two type of datetime ...

```
s.apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x, format="%d%m%Y") if x.isdigit() else pd.to_datetime(x, format="%d%b%Y"))

Out[360]: 
0   2017-06-29
1   2017-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: or `s.apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x, format="%d%{}%Y".format("m" if x.isdigit() else "b")))`

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to weigh in with some options

**Setup**

```
m = dict(
    JAN='01', FEB='02', MAR='03', APR='04',
    MAY='05', JUN='06', JUL='07', AUG='08',
    SEP='09', OCT='10', NOV='11', DEC='12'
)

m2 = m.copy()
m2.update({v: v for v in m.values()})

f = lambda x: m.get(x, x)
```

---

**Option 1**
list comprehension

```
pd.Series(
    pd.to_datetime(
        [x[:2] + f(x[2:5]) + x[5:] for x in s.values.tolist()],
        format='%d%m%Y'),
    s.index)

0   2017-06-29
1   2017-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

**Option 2**
Create a dataframe

```
pd.to_datetime(
    pd.DataFrame(dict(
        day=s.str[:2],
        year=s.str[-4:],
        month=s.str[2:-4].map(m2)
    )))

0   2017-06-29
1   2017-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Option 2B**
Create a dataframe

```
pd.to_datetime(
    pd.DataFrame(dict(
        day=s.str[:2],
        year=s.str[-4:],
        month=s.str[2:-4].map(f)
    )))

0   2017-06-29
1   2017-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Option 2C**
Create a dataframe
I estimate this to be the quickest

```
pd.to_datetime(
    pd.DataFrame(dict(
        day=s.str[:2].astype(int),
        year=s.str[-4:].astype(int),
        month=s.str[2:-4].map(m2).astype(int)
    )))

0   2017-06-29
1   2017-08-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

**Test**

```
s = pd.Series(["29062017", "01AUG2017"] * 100000)

%timeit pd.to_datetime(s.replace(m, regex=True), format='%d%m%Y')
%timeit pd.to_datetime(s.str[:2] + s.str[2:5].replace(m) + s.str[5:], format='%d%m%Y')
%timeit pd.to_datetime(s.str[:2] + s.str[2:5].map(f) + s.str[5:], format='%d%m%Y')
%timeit pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d%m%Y', errors='coerce').fillna(pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d%b%Y', errors='coerce'))
%timeit pd.Series(pd.to_datetime([x[:2] + f(x[2:5]) + x[5:] for x in s.values.tolist()], format='%d%m%Y'), s.index)
%timeit pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(dict(day=s.str[:2], year=s.str[-4:], month=s.str[2:-4].map(m2))))
%timeit pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(dict(day=s.str[:2], year=s.str[-4:], month=s.str[2:-4].map(f))))
%timeit pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(dict(day=s.str[:2].astype(int), year=s.str[-4:].astype(int), month=s.str[2:-4].map(m2).astype(int))))

1.39 s ± 24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
690 ms ± 17.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
613 ms ± 13.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
533 ms ± 14.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
529 ms ± 8.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
557 ms ± 13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
607 ms ± 26.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
328 ms ± 31.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I'd not seen that pd.to_datetime could take a DataFrame, I guess that has been cythonized and the datetime parser is (sadly) still python?  I am surprised it's fastest!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution for this problem:

```py
def set_date(col):
    # date_formates = ["21 June, 2018", "12/11/2018 09:15:32", "April-21" ]
    date_formats = ["%d %B, %Y", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%B-%y", "%d %B, %Y", "%m/%d/Y"] # Can add different date formats to this list to test
    for x in date_formats:
        col = pd.to_datetime(col, errors="ignore", format= f"{x}")

    col = pd.to_datetime(col, errors="coerce") # To remove errors in the columns like strings or numbers
    return col
```

Comment: I think this solution helps for any generalization to the issue, did you tried also to `%timeit` compared with some of the other methods ?