# pandas.to_datetime issue identifying correct format when using HKMA's Open API

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, economics

I am trying to identify the appropriate format used in my obtained dataframe, but I am having trouble finding anything that works.

The issue is that the format contains yearly figures for which the month is assumed to be some sort of zero-padded zeroth month. For example, the yearly nominal GDP is reported as 2014-00 instead of the usual 2014-01.

Thus, when I use,

```
df['end_of_month'] =pandas.to_datetime(df['end_of_month'], format="%Y-%m")
```

I get that:

```
ValueError: time data 2014-00 doesn't match format specified
```

For your consideration, here is the dataframe:

```
end_of_month  nominal_gdp
0       2014-00    2260005.0
1       2015-00    2398280.0
2       2016-00    2490617.0
3       2017-00    2662836.0
4       2018-00    2842883.0
5       2018-09     726352.0
6       2018-10          NaN
7       2018-11          NaN
8       2018-12     754904.0
9       2019-01          NaN
10      2019-02          NaN
11      2019-03     712514.0
12      2019-04          NaN
13      2019-05          NaN
14      2019-06     698044.0
15      2019-07          NaN
16      2019-08          NaN
17      2019-09     722831.0
18      2019-10          NaN
19      2019-11          NaN
```

For anyone interested or whomever might face a similar issue, the data was obtained from the Hong Kong Monetary Authority, using their Open API  initiative. For more info visit [HKMA's documentation](https://apidocs.hkma.gov.hk/).

Specifically, this issue arises when using the Economic Statistics dataset, which can be found in the following [page](https://apidocs.hkma.gov.hk/documentation/market-data-and-statistics/monthly-statistical-bulletin/financial/economic-statistics/) of the documentation.

Comment: Yes, what is `2014-00` supposed to mean? Becuase there is a `12` month value, therefore there are 13 possible values for each year?

Comment: How could there be both `00` and `12` in the month field?

Comment: Maybe `00` is the total sum of the corresponding year? Or some kind of aggregation?

Comment: The issue here is that when you see a yyyy-00 it's supposed to be a yearly frequency value of that respective year, whereas when you see a yyyy-01 it represents the monthly figure for January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I have managed to find a solution for the issue. Here is the link where I found how to solve it:
[Handling multiple datetime formats with pd.to_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256212/handling-multiple-datetime-formats-with-pd-to-datetime)

Here is the line I used:

```
df['end_of_month'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['end_of_month'], format='%Y-%m',errors='coerce').fillna(pandas.to_datetime(df['end_of_month'], format='%Y-00',errors='coerce'))
```

It simply "fills" the coerced rows with a different format. The format I used for the yearly figures whose zero-padded zeroth month has no meaning, is : "%Y-00" since we can diregard the "-00" which has no meaning for the yearly frequency values.