# Can pandas format individual dates in a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure that this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find a already existing question that has the same requirements as mine.

I have a CSV file with 3 columns, DATE, TOTAL and NAME.

```
           date   Total              name
0    2008-11-21      32     JOHN SMITH
1      08-25-21     7.9     JOHN SMITH
2      08-25-21     7.4     JOHN SMITH
3      08-27-21     100     JOHN SMITH
4    2008-04-21   36.62     JOHN SMITH
```

As you can see, there are 3 **DATES** that don't match the "yyyy-mm-dd" format. I want all the dates the follow the specified format. Is this something that is possible using Pandas?

Comment: Rows 1,2 and 3 have a issue of being both compatible in dd-mm-yyyy and yy-dd-mm. If you could select the rows and specify the formats, yes.

Comment: Usually, `pd.to_datetime()` is smart enough to infer the format on its own. So try the following: `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])` If this should fail, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256212/handling-multiple-datetime-formats-with-pd-to-datetime) to with a similar question which was likely solved. You can then convert is back to a string with your desired format: `df["date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: @psalt Thank you for this, this worked exactly how I needed it to.

Comment: `08-25-21` - does it mean `August 25, 2021`?

Comment: @mully I'm glad this was the solution for you. I posted my comment as an answer to your post so the solution is more visible in case others have a similar questions. If you like, you can mark that answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `pd.to_datetime()` is smart enough to infer the format on its own. To convert a series or a column of the dataframe to the datetime format you can use:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

You can then convert the series back to a string with the desired format:

```
df["date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

When working with (multiple) unusual formats you might need to use a different method, see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256212/handling-multiple-datetime-formats-with-pd-to-datetime).

Answer (score 1):

After importation and assuming they are imported as strings:

```
import numpy as np
df['date'] = np.where(len(df['date']) == 8, '20' + df['date'], df['date'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Following gtomer's suggestion and assuming these dates are wrongly formated and the format is the correct one you can also try with [.str.pad](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.pad.html):

```
s.str.pad(width=10, side='right', fillchar='20')
```