# Data Have to year format 19 and 2019 how to convert it into a single format 2019

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning

I am cleaning some data working on `Pandas` and have one column year containing two formats of years 19 and 2019.

I am currently using `pd.to_datetime(chelsea["Year"], format="%y")`

it is giving me errors. Now how can I convert this column into a single format like `2019`

ERROR is `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 93`

Comment: Where does `93` come from? Please include a simple repro.

Comment: What is the output of `chelsea["Year"].unique()`?

Comment: A total of 958 rows, so 93 may be unable to change

Comment: array(['93', '1993', '1994', '94', '95', '1995', '1996', '96', '1997',
       '97', '1998', '98', '1999', '99', '2000', '00', '2001', '01',
       '2002', '02', '2003', '03', '2004', '04', '2005', '05', '2006',
       '06', '2007', '07', '2008', '08', '2009', '09', '10', '2010',
       '2011', '11', '2012', '12', '2013', '13', '2014', '14', '2015',
       '15', '2016', '16', '2017', '17', '2018', '18'], dtype=object)

These are different years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [Handling multiple datetime formats with pd.to_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256212/handling-multiple-datetime-formats-with-pd-to-datetime)

In short, you can use `errors=coerce` to fill any years not matching a pattern with NaT. If you repeat that for all patterns you have in the data, you can then combine the different results together:

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series(["2019", "73", "2020", "01", "13", "1998", "99"])

one = pd.to_datetime(ser, format="%Y", errors="coerce")
two = pd.to_datetime(ser, format="%y", errors="coerce")

out = one.fillna(two)
```

out:

```
0   2019-01-01
1   1973-01-01
2   2020-01-01
3   2001-01-01
4   2013-01-01
5   1998-01-01
6   1999-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

you can convert those back to just the year:

```
years = out.dt.strftime("%Y")
```

Comment: Why the output is with 01-01 Month and Day

Comment: because it's in datetime format. You can use the final piece of code to only get the year as a string