# Converting string column to date time when strings slightly differ in format due to GMT specification

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df` with a columns that contains, in two different string format, several timestamps.

These are the two formats:

```
fmt = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y"
fmt_2 = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
```

[Thanks to this community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283198/a-function-that-uses-a-regex-to-parse-date-and-time-and-returns-a-datetime-objec/283219#283219), if I had just one type of string format I would be able to convert to `datetime` using

`.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, fmt)`

```
stamp = "Fri Oct 11 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019"
stamp_2 = 'Sun Oct 27 08:05:47 GMT 2019'
stamp_3 = 'Sat Oct 26 08:05:47 GMT 2019'
stamp_4 = "Sat Oct 12 15:09:30 GMT+01:00 2019"

#How I would convert the two format
#from string to datetime
#
fmt = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y"
print(datetime.strptime(stamp, fmt))
fmt_2 = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
print(datetime.strptime(stamp_2, fmt_2))

#building an example dataframe
question_dict = {"time":[stamp, stamp_2,
                           stamp_3,stamp_4],
                 "record":[1,2,3,4]}
question_df = pd.DataFrame(question_dict)
print(question_df.info())
```

How can I convert the elements in my column from string to datetime?

I tried to search but please let me know if my question is a duplicate.

Comment: I would suggest using `pd.to_datetime` twice (once for each format) on your column with `errors="coerce"`. Example in this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256212/handling-multiple-datetime-formats-with-pd-to-datetime

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs thank you it is very similar to my problem, and I think my question is clearly a duplicate. I think can be useful to keep this question linking to the question you shared.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` without a format would be enough.

Comment: Since you have mixed UTC offsets, you'll end up with data type 'object'. If you want the pandas datetime64 data type, use `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=True)`.

Comment: @FObersteiner @Quang Hoang thank you for the suggestions and for linking the right questions, I really appreciate that.  I actually tried ` pd.to_datetime(df['time]'` before asking but it was giving me an object, while I wanted a datetime64 and I got confused :)