# Python-Pandas- Memory - Handling Multiple date formats

Tags: python, pandas, date, memory

I have multiple data sets for which a column - "Created date" to be handled because of multiple dateformats it has. Hence used the below code. However due to the lots of data in the dataset which is in millions it is taking soo much time to execute the below code. What can be done to execute faster ?

Code:

```
Appilication1['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication1['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication2['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication2['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication3['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication3['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication4['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication4['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication5['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication5['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication6['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication6['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication7['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication7['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication8['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication8['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication9['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication9['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication10['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication10['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication11['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication11['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
Appilication12['Created Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Appilication12['Created Date'], dayfirst=True,errors = 'coerce')
```

Comment: `because of multiple dateformats it has` - is possible specify formats?

Comment: input format is : mm-dd-yyyy  h:min:sec or mm/dd/yyyy or  mm-dd-yyyy and some invalid formats and to be converted to i.e. output =  DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:sec

Comment: I think need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256212/handling-multiple-datetime-formats-with-pd-to-datetime)